# UIButton in UIScrollview inside UItableViewCell handle event with data

Tags: ios, xcode, events, uitableview, uiscrollview

[image]

I have an CustomUIScrollView that have many CustomUIButton inside (each button is a news item that have an image and title --> each button have a news ID

When touch inside button, the touchupInside event fire --> everything is OK
But i want when touch in button, a detail news Page, detailViewController, will create and push into navigationController (like BBC NEWS app in Store) and the detail Page will load webpage has ID equal with ID of Button we has touched.

My tableviewController is rootViewController, how can I pass event with ID data from Button in Scrollview inside UITableViewCell to my rootviewController to push a new DetailViewController

Thank in advance. (See picture make more easy to understand)

Answer (score 1):

`enter code here`Hi i used this code try this..

in this code i pass button tag form calling method and compare to called method and then take your action whatever you need.

Thank You

```
    -(IBAction)btnpress:(id)sender
     {
      UIButton *btn = (UIButton *)sender;
       NSLog(@"%d",btn.tag);

       if(img_alphabet.tag == btn.tag)
         {

          }
       }
```